# WindowManager: MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40731aa0 that was original

Tags: java, android

What does mean this warning? I develop an android application and i see this warning in the logcat. This warning doesn't lead to close the application. Everything runs without any problems or interrrupts but could it lead some problems which are unseen in my application?

```
Continue logcat:    at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:261)
                        atandroid.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:170)....
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for this Exception is, your `Activity` is being destroyed by calling either `finish()` in `Activity` or by some other `Exception` is thrown in the `Activity` while your `Dialog` is showing..

The solution is to call `dismiss()` on the Dialog you created in view before exiting the Activity, e.g. in `onPause()`. All windows&dialogs should be closed before leaving an Activity.If you dont dismiss the dialog it will give you that exception..

Like below

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (dialog!=null) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I use dismiss() in wrong place in my code. I'll rethink and reorganize my code for closing all windows&dialogs before leaving an Activity.