# android-HttpResponse getting error when run on phone

Tags: android, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient, httpentity

I'm posting data to a php server , it works fine and then i get the response . 
When I want to read the response ,it shows me this error

```
Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2c2a6848 that was originally added here
```

It's exaclty from this code that reads the response :

```
                    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                switch(responseCode) {
                case 200:
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if(entity != null) {
                        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        Log.v("this", responseBody);
                    }
                    break;
                }
```

this is my whole code:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlpostdata);
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", et.getText().toString()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                switch(responseCode) {
                case 200:
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if(entity != null) {
                        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        Log.v("this", responseBody);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("this",e.getMessage().toString());
            }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }


}
```

Could you help me to solve it?

Comment: Can you post the full logcat ?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295073/windowmanager-mainactivity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-p?answertab=active#tab-top)